Allowing "Negotiate Changes" via the DocuSign API
I'm wanting to allow "Negotiate Changes" for an agreement in an envelope sent via the DocuSign API, in line with this: https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=gbo1643332197980&topicId=hgz1578456364517.html&_LANG=enus
However, I can't see how to do this via the API, as it's not clear what property/ies would be applicable. Is it AllowMarkup? If so, for this scenario we have an Enterprise account so I thought we would have rights for this option, but I'm getting:
{"errorCode":"CANNOT_ALLOW_MARKUP","message":"Account does not have permission to set Allow Markup."}
So is this the right property, and if so what rights would be missing?

Regarding your inquiry about enabling the Document Markup feature, you can achieve this by utilizing the 'allowMarkup' property within the createEnvelope method. This property, when set to true, activates the Document Markup feature. However, it's essential to note that both account-level and envelope-level settings must have Document Markup enabled for this feature to function properly. It's worth mentioning that only Admin users have the authority to modify this setting at the account level.
The AllowMarkup feature is classified as a premium feature. Therefore, it's possible that it might be disabled for your account. To address this issue, I recommend initiating a case with our Account Services Team. They will assess the availability of this feature within your plan and activate it if deemed appropriate.
Best regards,
Leandro Reis

Thanks Leandro, I didn't realise there was an "account" level setting as well. This is now on for our account and I'm testing again, and the doc now allows markup. However, when I test (I'm testing as an external party using my private email and as the internal signer using my corporate email account), then I can markup as the external, and initial the markup, but it didn't require me to counter-initial (and even worse, didn't notify me about the existence of the markup) as the internal counter-signatory. Am I missing something?

Per the original doc I linked above: "All changes must be reviewed and approved by all signers." - this is what I was expecting, that it would flag to me that there was a change, and require me (as internal counterparty) to acknowledge, via initials.

any response for me on this by any chance?

I've logged a support ticket now regarding this.

Leandro, I'm REALLY struggling to get an answer from DocuSign - very frustrating especially considering we have a premium account. There's no update here, where it could benefit others, nor on my ticket in the support centre (13347663). Please assist urgently.
